# what will be the answer for 888=?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

I found this puzzle on another website and I wanted to share it here.
I will post the source link after a week to avoid spoilers.

Here are some rules:

if:

```
 111 = 09
 444 = 12
 777 = 15
```

then:

```
 888 = ?
```

Answer:

[Click Here](http://www.puzzles-world.com/2016/08/puzzle-if-111-09-444-12-777-15-then-888.html)

Comment: Whats not clear in this question should i know..??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just ...

> ... spelling math I think?
>
> - one one one is 9 letters
> - four four four is 12 letters
> - seven seven seven is 15 letters
>
> so eight eight eight  Would be 15 letters.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the (perhaps too) obvious answer is that

> the RHS increases by 3 for every 333 increase on the LHS. Then 888=16

Answer (score 2):

18

> Ignore the triple numbers. It is the same like 9,12,15,... so the answer must be 18

Comment: Are you sure? As in such a case 09, 12, 15, __ could have been the question then, instead of an equation based question.

Answer (score -5):

For 888 it is

> 24

As,

> 888 = 111 + 777 or 2 × 444. That is either 09 + 15 or 2 x 12 which is 24.

Comment: If that were true, then given `111 = 09`, `444 = 36`.